# Get `Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string()` after update database

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I try to make my custom code to update data to my custom database table
after I send the data I get:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 2 to be string,
>   array given in .../wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1156

My table structure is:
table name: `wp_wlm_user_options`
column names: `ID`, `user_id`, `option_name`, `option_value`

My code is:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $table = 'wp_wlm_user_options';

    $meta = array();
    foreach ($wlm_user_info as $key => $value) {
        $get_meta = $value['option_name'];
        array_push($meta, $get_meta);
    }

    //var_dump($meta);

    $value = array(
         'custom_firstname' => $_POST['first_name'],
         'custom_lastname' => $_POST['last_name'],
         'custom_text_dateofbirth' => $_POST['text_dateofbirth'],
         'custom_radio_gender' => $_POST['radio_gender'],
         'custom_landlinephone' => $_POST['landlinephone'],
         'custom_GoogleHangoutsId' => $_POST['GoogleHangoutsId']
    );
    $format = array(
         '%s',
         '%s'
    );

    //print_r($meta,$value);

    $data = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'option_name' => $meta,
        'option_value' => maybe_serialize($value)
    );

    $format = array('%d','%s','%s');

    $where = array(
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'option_name' => $meta
    );

    $x = $wpdb->update($table, $data, $where, $format);
    //$x = $wpdb->update($table, $data, $where);
    if($x){
        echo '<h1>data has been save</h1>' ;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: I guess `'option_name' => $meta` is the problem, since `$meta` is an array. What does `var_dump($meta);` output? Should it be imploded into a string?

Comment: any idea to fix ?

Comment: Not without further information. What is `var_dump($wlm_user_info)`? What is your table structure?

Comment: my table it `wp_wlm_user_options`
ID,user_id,option_name,option_value ;
$wlm_user_info => from i query wp_wlm_user_options table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to your poor information we can only guess.

You might want something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
  $table = 'wp_wlm_user_options';
  $values = array(
    'custom_firstname'        => $_POST['first_name'      ],
    'custom_lastname'         => $_POST['last_name'       ],
    'custom_text_dateofbirth' => $_POST['text_dateofbirth'],
    'custom_radio_gender'     => $_POST['radio_gender'    ],
    'custom_landlinephone'    => $_POST['landlinephone'   ],
    'custom_GoogleHangoutsId' => $_POST['GoogleHangoutsId']
  );

  $format      = array('%s');
  $whereformat = array('%d','%s');

  foreach($values as $key => $val)
  {
    $data = array(
      'option_value' => maybe_serialize($val)
    );

    $where = array(
      'user_id' => $user_id,
      'option_name' => $key
    );

    $num_rows = $wpdb->update($table, $data, $where, $format, $whereformat);
    if($num_rows !== false){
      echo "<h1>$key has been saved</h1>" ;
    }
  }
};
```

The code above does multiple updates mapping the data to `option_name` and `option_value` for each `update()` invocation. You don't need to update fields of the `WHERE` clause with unchanged values.

You can find the official documentation on [wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows)